# Encryption using two keys

Tags: encryption

Suppose we have two secret keys K<sub>1</sub> and K<sub>2</sub>, I'd like to ask if there is any encryption scheme that allows us to derive another key K<sub>12</sub> from K<sub>1</sub>, and K<sub>2</sub> and for a message x, E<sub>K<sub>12</sub></sub>(x) = E<sub>K<sub>1</sub></sub>(E<sub>K<sub>2</sub></sub>(x)).

E<sub>K</sub>(x) is the encrypted text of x using key K.

Comment: Are you looking for a symmetric or an asymmetric encryption scheme?

Comment: It'd be good if the encryption scheme is symmetric

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no (classical) symmetric encryption scheme / algorithm that fulfills this requirement, but I think it *may* be possible construct a scheme that can do this using fancy number or group theory maths, although it would be highly non-standard (I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with a symmetric system.

One way would be if we had a public prime $p$, and secret keys $k_1, k_2$ which are values relatively prime to $p-1$.

And, we define $E_k(M) = M^k \bmod p$; decryption then is $D_k(M) = M^{k^{-1} \bmod p-1} \bmod p$ (the value $k^{-1} \bmod p-1$ is easy to compute, given $k$).

And, for $K_{12} = K_1 \cdot K_2 \bmod p-1$, we have $E_{K_{12}}(M) = E_{K_1}(E_{K_2}(M))$

Comment: Funfact: This is conceptually RSA without public exponents and with a non-composite modulus.

Comment: @SEJPM: except that RSA is asymmetric, and this is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you poncho! What would you say about how secure this scheme is?

Comment: @tienthanh411: it does have the distinguisher that, given $E_k(M)$, you can determine whether $M$ was a quadratic residue.  Other than that, it should be safe, assuming $p$ was a large enough safeprime, say, 2048 bits.